# a question about the well ordering principle

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading folland real analysis

I have question about the well ordering principle .every non empty set X can be well ordered

He Proof Let W be the collection of well orderings of subsets of X.

I can understand why there exist well ordering s of subsets of X.i think should proof this.or I just admit it.

Comment: I am not understanding the question. Do you want to prove that, in any given set X, we can define an order relation that makes X a well-ordered set?

Comment: yes i want to proof this use zorn’s theorem.i don’t understand the sentence in folland’s book means,that sentence is let W be the collection of well ordering of subsets of X.can you explain it to me

Comment: You should then state rhat you want to prove it from Zorn's Lemma. BTW in pite of its name, Zorn's Lemma is an axiom. not provable from the other axioms of Set Theory.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I thought it was provable from the Axiom of Choice... :)

Comment: There do indeed exist subsets of $X$ that can be well-ordered, so $W$ is not empty. For example, $\varnothing$ is such a subset; so is $\{x\}$ for any particular $x\in X$. Whether you should prove this depends on whether it's actually used in the rest of the proof. (It need not be used, but maybe Folland formulated the proof in a way that assumes $W\neq\varnothing$.)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Formally, since the axiom of choice, Zorn's lemma, the well-ordering principle, and lots of other things are equivalent, one could declare any one of them to be an axiom and deduce the rest as theorems. But for foundational purposes, it's much better to take the axiom of choice as an axiom and deduce the others, because the axiom of choice is much more obviously true (for the usual meaning of "set"). So one usually regards Zorn's lemma as a theorem, not an axiom.

Comment: @AndreasBlass . I know. I had a feeling the proposer might not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach is to look at all the subsets of $S$ which can be well-ordered, and all possible well-orderings on each one of them. In other words, the objects we study are pairs $(X,<)$ where $X\subseteq S$ and $<$ is a well-order on $X$. That means that the same $X$ can be part of many different pairs. We collect all these pairs in a set, and give this set the name $W$.

Clearly, some subsets of $S$ (like the finite ones) can be well-ordered, so $W$ is non-empty. However, a priori, there may be subsets (chiefly among them $S$ itself) which cannot be well-ordered, and therefore isn't part of any pair in $W$. This is where Zorn's lemma comes in.

On $W$, we introduce a partial order $\leq$ the following way: For two pairs $(X_1,<_1), (X_2,<_2)$, we write
$$
(X_1,<_1)\leq(X_2,<_2)
$$
if and only if all of the following are satisfied:

- $X_1\subseteq X_2$
- $<_2$, when restricted to $X_1$, is equal to $<_1$
- Any element of $X_2\setminus X_1$ is greater than any element of $X_1$, according to $<_2$

In other words, one pair is bigger than the other iff it is an extension (to the right). For instance, if $S=\Bbb Z$, then $(\{1,2,3\},<)\leq(\{1,2,3,4,5\}, <)$ (using the standard ordering on the integers), but $(\{1,2,3\},<)\not\leq(\{0,1,2,4,5\},<)$, both because $3$ isn't in the subset on the right side, but also because $0$ doesn't come after $1,2$ and $3$.

Any totally ordered chain of these pairs has an upper bound: Their union. Take the union of all the subsets in the chain, take the union of all the orderings. This is a new pair, and this pair is still a well-ordering on a subset of $S$, and therefore this pair is an element of $W$ (this should be proven in more detail). According to Zorn's lemma, then, there is a maximal element of $W$. One can prove by contradiction that this maximal pair must be a well-ordering on all of $S$ (if it's not all of $S$, then one can add one more element to it, so it's not maximal).

Comment: Thank you ,now I understand ,do you mean we can define a w,and w is no empty ,and we define a partially ordering on w,for every subset of w ,we have upper bound ,so has a maximal element ,then we denote the maximal element as E ,for any y$\in$ X\E,we can define x<y,then we proof X can be well ordered

Comment: @jackson That's the gist of it, yeah. "for every **totally ordered** subset of w ,we have upper bound" is important, though.